# How to write tiff file using rasterio?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

In the code below, I  am trying to write a dataset. The `GTiff` file has data and the image is clear but when I run the below code, the result of

```
dataset.write(total.astype(rasterio.uint16), 1)
```

is a black image.

Please let me know how to read part of a `tiff` file and write it to a file.

**code**:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
from rasterio.windows import Window
import rasterio.features
import rasterio.warp
import numpy as np

with rasterio.open('M:/tiffs/MOS_EU_LAEA_2000/MOS_EU_LAEA_2000.tif', 'w+', driver='GTiff', height='360', width='360', count=3, dtype='uint16', transform=from_origin(-180.0, 90.0, 9.5, 9.5)) as dataset:
    print(dataset)
    r,g,b = dataset.read()
    print(r)
    print(g)
    print(b)

    total = np.zeros(r.shape)
    print(total)
    for band in r, g, b:
        total += band
    total /= 3
    print(dataset.profile)
    dataset.write(total.astype(rasterio.uint16), 1)
```

Comment: `rasterio` has a pretty [detailed docs section](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#opening-a-dataset-in-writing-mode) on how to write to GTiff